# SQL Statement to Track the Number of Defects Opened Each Day By Application

Tags: sql

I use Quality Center to track defects, I believe it uses MSSQL language.
I have a table that has the following fields: defectID, summary, application, severity, status, createDate, closedDate. Will just cover the relevant fields.

```
defectID application severity createDate closedDate
-------- ----------- -------- ---------- ---------
1        app1        sev1     3/10/2010  3/23/2010
2        app1        sev1     3/15/2010  3/23/2010
3        app2        sev1     3/14/2010  3/25/2010
4        app1        sev2     3/18/2010  3/24/2010
5        app1        sev1     3/15/2010  3/19/2010
6        app1        sev1     3/25/2010
```

I need the SQL to output the number of sev1 defects that were open on a given date. I would like to supply the date range. Here is the output sample? Some where in the SQL I will identify the start date of 3/22 and an end date of 3/26

```
application 3/22 3/23 3/24 3/25 3/26
---------------------------------------
app1        3    1    0    1    1
app2        1    1    1    0    0
```

If the app as to be horizontal (list going across) and date has to be vertical (list going down) that is fine. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make it a table yourself, but

```
SELECT createDate, application, COUNT(*) FROM Defects GROUP BY createDate, application
```

should give you the data.  If you want the data to come directly from your RDBMS exactly as you've drawn it you'll have to dynamically create the query like the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.application,
         SUM(CASE WHEN '3/22/2010' BETWEEN t.createdate AND t.closedate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "3/22",
         SUM(CASE WHEN '3/23/2010' BETWEEN t.createdate AND t.closedate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "3/23",
         SUM(CASE WHEN '3/24/2010' BETWEEN t.createdate AND t.closedate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "3/24"
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.application
```

I didn't do them all, but there's enough of an example.  Dynamic date ranges require the use of dynamic SQL.

Comment: @OMG-Ponies - It doesn't consider unclosed dates. Something like this:

 SUM(CASE WHEN '3/22/2010' BETWEEN t.createdate AND coalesce(t.closedate,'3/22/2010') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "3/22",

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am working through the solution. There is one criteria I forgot to account for and that is what if defect was a sev3 on 3/22 and 3/23, then raised to a sev1 on 3/24. So, when I run the SQL for 3/24 or any day after, it will include that defect in those counts for 3/22 and 3/23. To resolve I think I have to find out how to check what the sev was for that date before including in the that days count. I have a table that captures the audit history of the date of change, defect number, field change, old value and new value.

Comment: While trying to figure that out, my brain shutdown from overload which is why it took me awhile to respond back. I appreciate the help, it got me very close. Now, I just need to account for this criteria. Any help on that is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A lazy afternoon produced chaos that you can possibly use... Its a little dirty, but it seems to work :D

This is mostly a modified version of the answer above with case statements, just using the pivot command. Note this will only work in Sql Server 2005 and above. If you have 2000, then you will have to use the case method above in a dynamic way.

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime
declare @Dates varchar(max)
declare @nums varchar(max)
select @startdate = '3/22/10', @endDate = '3/26/10', @Dates = '', @nums = ''

;with nums as (
    select row_number() over (order by object_id)-1 as num from sys.objects        
)
select @dates = '' + '[' + convert(varchar(8),num) + '] as ' + '''' + cast(Dateadd(day,num,@StartDate) as varchar(11)) + ''',' + @dates
,@nums = '[' + convert(varchar(8),num) + '],' + @nums
    from nums
    where num between 1 and DateDiff(day,@StartDatE,@EndDate)
    order by num desc

select @dates = substring(@dates,0,len(@dates)),  @nums = substring(@nums,0,len(@nums))

declare @qry varchar(max)
set @qry = ';with nums as (
    select row_number() over (order by object_id)-1 as num from sys.objects        
)
select AppName, ' + @dates + ' from (select [Application],[Application] as AppName, num as cnt from ##temp
    cross join nums 
        where num between 1 and ' + convert(varchar(8),DateDiff(day,@StartDatE,@EndDate)) + '+1
        and Dateadd(day,num,''' + cast(@StartDate as varchar(11)) +''') between CreateDate and closeddate
        ) as p
    pivot (count([Application]) for [cnt] in (' +@nums + ')) as pvt'

exec (@qry)
```